# Persist a Jenkins environment variable from Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, environment-variables

I have a job that needs to cycle through numbered databases each time it runs.  I'm trying to do this without having to write out to a file, as this job could execute on any of 4 different slaves.

I wrote the following Groovy to try and accomplish this, but although it makes the environment variable DATABASE available to the current thread, this value is not saved with the job; therefore when I try to query it in the next run of this same, it's always null.

Is there a way I can save this environment variable into the currently running job for future reference?

```
import hudson.model.*

def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('smoke-test')  
def lastBuild = job.getLastBuild()

def lastDatabase = lastBuild.getEnvironment()["DATABASE"]
println "Last database was " + lastDatabase

def databaseToTest = ""
switch (lastDatabase) {
  case 6..9: 
        databaseToTest=lastDatabase+1
    break
  case 10:
  default:
        databaseToTest=6
}

println "New database is " + databaseToTest

def pa = new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("DATABASE", databaseToTest.toString())
])
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)
```